# Automator: combine images as PDF with useful file name

Tags: applescript, automator, pdf

I have an Automator service (see below) which takes a folder of images and combines into a PDF.

But I would like the name of the PDF to be based on the name of the first (or any) of the images.

I.e., if the images in the folder are

- ProjectFoo-Frame1.png
- ProjectFoo-Frame2.png
- ProjectFoo-Frame3.png

I want the PDF to be called something like "ProjectFoo-Frame1.pdf"

Been scratching my head with Automator variables and can't make sense of it. Maybe I need to do this with pure Applescript.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I would like the name of the PDF to be based on the name of the first (or any) of the images.

Note that the following was tested and works for me as shown, under **macOS Catalina**, to have the created **PDF** *document* named for the name of the first *file* in the *sorted files list*.

With the **Automator** *Quick Action* set to **Workflow receives current [folders] in [Finder]**, the following ***actions*** achieve the goal.

- **Get Folder Contents**

  - [] Repeat for each subfolder found
- **Sort Finder Items**

  - by [name] in [ascending] order
- **Set Value of Variable**

  - Variable: **sortedFiles**
- **Run AppleScript**

  ```
    on run {input, parameters}
        tell application "Finder" to ¬
            return displayed name of ¬
                first item of input
    end run
  ```
- **Set Value of Variable**

  - Variable: **fileName**
- **Get Value of Variable**

  - Variable: **sortedFiles**
  - **Options**
  - [√] Ignore this action's input
- **New PDF from Images**

  - Save output to: [**2020_Projects**]
  - Output File Name: **New PDF from Images Output**
- **Rename Finder Items: Name Single File**

  - [Name Single Item]
  - Name: [Basename only] to [**fileName**]

    - **Note:** Drag and drop the **fileName** *variable* to the **to** *field*.
- **Reveal Finder Items**